# remove the first zeros of filename

Tags: windows, filenames

I found some topics to change the name or remove a part of the name with a batch code on windows but not that I search.

I have some files named :

XXX***000***1.scl1
XXX***000***2.scl1
XXX***000***3.scl1
XXX***000***4.scl1
...
XXX***000***9.scl1
XXX***00***10.scl1
XXX***00***11.scl1
...
XXX***00***99.scl1
XXX***0***100.scl1
XXX***0***101.scl1

I want to remove the first zeros (in italic and bold) of each name

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't think he has been able to try anything, since he cannot even find something that *might* work. His problem is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Padding* rule in [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer), designed specifically for this task, i.e. remove leading zeros in numbers.

[image: Remove leading zeros using ReNamer]

[image: Padding rule confgiuration]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rename`](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) command-line tool available for Windows, Linux and Unix (since it's a perl script).

Sample syntax to remove all leading zeros (to see what's renamed, add `-v` parameter):

```
rename 's/0*([0-9]*)/$1/g' *.scl1
```

To use full features of wildcards, install it in *Bash on Windows*, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install rename
```

---

Testing steps in Bash on Windows:

```
$ touch XXX0001.scl1
$ for i in $(seq -w 0001 00011); do touch XXX$i.scl1; done
$ ls
XXX00001.scl1  XXX00003.scl1  XXX00005.scl1  XXX00007.scl1  XXX00009.scl1  XXX00011.scl1
XXX00002.scl1  XXX00004.scl1  XXX00006.scl1  XXX00008.scl1  XXX00010.scl1
$ rename 's/0*([0-9]*)/$1/g' *.scl1
$ ls
XXX10.scl1  XXX1.scl1  XXX3.scl1  XXX5.scl1  XXX7.scl1  XXX9.scl1
XXX11.scl1  XXX2.scl1  XXX4.scl1  XXX6.scl1  XXX8.scl1
```

Comment: errors out invalit syntax windows cmd

Comment: Try to use double-quotes instead of single-quotes. Or try in Bash on Windows.

Comment: based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102375/4535386 you cant use reg ex with ren

Comment: I've just tested it in Bash on Windows and it works. I've improved the answer by adding the testing steps.